# How to update a single column in LINQ without loading the entire row?

Tags: c#, linq, performance, linq-to-sql

In LinqToSql, it is lovely easy to load a row, change a column, and submit the changes to the database:

```
using (MyDataContext wdc = new MyDataContext())
{        
  Article article = wdc.Article.First(p => p.ID == id);
  article.ItemsInStock = itemsinstock;
  wdc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The only drawback: Article is huge. **To load the entire article, just to update one column is way overkill** and slows down my app significantly.

Is there a way to update a single column using LINQ, without having to load the entire row?

Right now I revert to using ExecuteCommand where speed is of essence, but this is ugly and error prone:

```
wdc.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE Article SET ItemsInStock = @1 WHERE ID = @2", itemsinstock,id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ligget78 gave me another idea how to make an update of a single column:

Create a new DataContext just for this kind of update, and only include the needed columns into this DataContext.

This way the unneeded columns will not even be loaded, and of course not sent back to the database.

Comment: can you give an example of how exactly you did this please, thank you

Comment: I'll give you an upvote if you would kindly give us an example.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set UpdateCheck on all properties of the Article class except the primary key (click on the class property in LINQ2SQL designer and switch to Properties Tool Window) to Never (not sure about WhenChanged, maybe that works too - go ahead and experiment with it!).

This will force LINQ2SQL to use

```
UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ID = @2
```

instead of the long version with all columns in the WHERE-clause:

```
  UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ID = @2 AND ItemsInStock = @1 AND SomeOtherColumn = @3 AND...
```

Now you can use code like

```
context.Articles.Attach(article /* article with updated values */, new Article { ID = articleID, ItemsInStock = -1 } /* pretend that this is the original article */);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Basically you indicate that only ItemsInStock property has changed - other props should have the same default value, articleID of course being the same.

NOTE: you don't need to fetch the article prior to that.

Comment: It is the loading of the article which is slow and unnecessary- the update, too, of course, but my main concern right now was loading it in the first place.

Comment: As I indicated you don't need to fetch the entity just for the sake of update here.

Comment: Ah, yes, now I understand. Would need to create a special version of my DataClasses, though.

Comment: You don't need to.Just pass in ID and ItemsInStock to your repository method. You can create 2 brand new object for context.Articles.Attach() - first one with changed values, the last one with fake values, e.g. ItemsInStock = -1.

Comment: Still changing all properties to 'never check' is not good for my shared DataContext. But you gave me an idea for a very very very simple solution: create a new DataContext just for this instance, which contains only the columns I want to update. Great!

Comment: I did not even know about the Attach() method, and for me, it's definitely the preferred solution. I included it in my article on different solutions to this problem http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/updating-a-single-column-in-linq-to-sql-summary/

Answer (score -1):

it wil  work fine
ExecuteCommand("UPDATE tIdx_TicketActivity SET Archive = {0} WHERE ExpiryTimeStamp