# LINQ to Entity Select Query Error

Tags: c#, linq, select, entity

```
using (SmartEntities employeeverificationcontext = new SmartEntities())
{
    Employee emp = (from c in employeeverificationcontext.EmployeeEntity 
                    where c.Employee_ID == emp_detail.EmployeeID 
                    select new Employee {c.Status}).FirstOrDefault();
    emp.Status = emp_detail.Status;
    int i=employeeverificationcontext.SaveChanges();
    if (i > 0)
    {
        result = "Verification Process Completed";
    }
}
```

> error: Error   1   Cannot initialize type 'SmartWCF.Employee' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `select new Employee {c.Status}` you should select the current object (`c`)

So your query should be:

```
Employee emp = (from c in employeeverificationcontext.EmployeeEntity 
               where c.Employee_ID == emp_detail.EmployeeID 
               select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
Employee emp = employeeverificationcontext.EmployeeEntity
                      .FirstOrDefault(c=> Employee_ID == emp_detail.EmployeeID);
```

Comment: i did that, but its selecting all the columns i just want to select status column...Thnks Help Appreciated.

Comment: @PushkarJethwa,  You can select the status column only, with `select c.status` without `new Employee`. You can't project to an entity type from Entity framework. But selecting the status won't help you what you are doing later in your code. You won't be able to set `emp.Status = emp_detail.Status`

Answer (score 0):

Only selecting the `Status` is done like this:

```
var employeeStatus = (from c in employeeverificationcontext.EmployeeEntity 
                        where c.Employee_ID == emp_detail.EmployeeID 
                      select c.Status).FirstOrDefault();
```

But if you want to set it to a new status and save that to your data context, this won't help you. You do have to select the `Employee` in that case.

There are a few alternatives mentioned in this post: [How to update a single column in LINQ without loading the entire row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221475/how-to-update-a-single-column-in-linq-without-loading-the-entire-row)

Comment: Thanks for reply..it means there is no way select only specific column in Employee emp;

Comment: You can easily select a single column, it's updating it that makes it a little more complicated. I added a link to another post in my answer.